# Events does not appear when making an Outlook query from Excel

Tags: excel, outlook, powerquery

I'm making an Excel sheet that helps me fill in my oursheet. To accomplish this I create a Power Query that takes data from my Outlook Calendar. However, I have noticed that recurring events only appears once. Also, there is nothing in the query that helps me figure out which events are recurring?

Can anybody help me get the recurring events into Excel through the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a conceptual shot in the dark from me, but if you're connecting to Exchange Online (from New Query -> Online Services -> Exchange Online) then you should see a column named Attributes, with records in it. If you look within those records, you should see each record has a field named AppointmentType--that might help you. There is also an IsRecurring field--which might be even more helpful. Further, there is a field called Recurrence, with a record in it that provides info about the recurrences, if any. Lastly, a FirstOccurence field and a LastOccurence field are also included, and might help you in some way as well.

I would think to first identify the recurring records (maybe based off the IsRecurring field, then get their attribute info related to each recurrence (most of which seems to be in the Recurrence field for each record) to construct the single entry items for the recurrences.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly the help I needed!

Comment: Ok. So by going through the data, it seems as if a lot of the recurring records simply has "error" on all their Attributes. Also, some of the recurring events are reported as FALLS in the IsRecurring field. I don't know why this is. But if I recreate the event it works. Looks like using a power quoery isn't gonna help me out. :-(